# PHP & HTML: Create PDF from HTML table/page and then send it as an attachment

Tags: php, email, pdf

I am trying to either copy a HTML page with a table made by jQuery and then create a PDF from that page. Or, I have also tried creating a PDF from a HTML page using FPDF but with no success.

What I am trying to do is to have my code create / make a PDF from the html page with the table and its contents in it (Note below that `$txt` is the table we suppose to bring over).  Once the PDF has been made, then send the PDF to the office email, and then to the client's emails with an HTML summary of the previous form they chose.

I have tried to create a message to PDF and then send as attachment, but the system will not send as attachment.  Nothing shows up and the HTML email is also wrecked.   I have also tried using FPDF and the writeHTML(), and I can then create the PDF but it doesn't show the table and doesn't send the PDF as attachment to the email.

I have tried multiple things, but cannot seem to get it to work. Is there a way to do this without using FPDF?  Is there a better way to create the PDF from html page and then just send it as an attachment?

Sample code of what I have been doing is below:

```
    <?php
    // download fpdf class (http://fpdf.org)
    require ("FPDF/fpdf.php");
    require ("WriteHTML.php"); 
    $pdf=new PDF_HTML(); 
    //$pdf-->AliasNbPages();
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 15);

    // fpdf object
    $pdf->AddPage();

    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',14);
    $pdf->WriteHTML('
    <h1>Vanguard Appraisals Price Estimate</h1>
    ');

    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',7);

    $htmlTable='
    <table align=\"center\"  style=\"width:85%; ;\">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" align="center" style="text-align:center;" >
                <span style="text-transform:uppercase; font-weight:bold; font-size:20px; text-align:center;">Contact Information</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left" style="background-color:#eee; padding-left:10px; width:20%; ">
                <b>Sales:</b>
            </td>
            <td align="left" style="padding-left:10px; background-color:#ffffff; width:30%;">
                '.$Sales.'
            </td>
            <td align="left" style="background-color:#eee; padding-left:10px; width:20%;">
                <b>Sales E-Mail:</b>
            </td>
            <td align="left" style="padding-left:10px; background-color:#ffffff; width:30%;">
                '.$from.'
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left" style="background-color:#eee; padding-left:10px; width:20%; ">
                <b>client Name:</b>
            </td>
            <td align="left" style="padding-left:10px; background-color:#ffffff; width:30%;">
                '.$client.'
            </td>
            <td align="left" style="background-color:#eee; padding-left:10px; width:20%; ">
                <b>Company, State:</b>
            </td>
            <td align="left" style="padding-left:10px; background-color:#ffffff; width:30%;">
                '.$Company.', '.$state.'
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left" style="background-color:#eee; padding-left:10px; width:20%; ">
                <b>client Phone:</b>
            </td>
            <td align="left" style="padding-left:10px; background-color:#ffffff; width:30%;">
                '.$client_phone.'
            </td>
            <td align="left" style="background-color:#eee; padding-left:10px; width:20%; ">
                <b>client E-mail:</b>
            </td>
            <td align="left" style="padding-left:10px; background-color:#ffffff; width:30%;">
                '.$email_from.'
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table align="center" width="100%" style="width:100%;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                '.$txt.'
            </td>   
        </tr>
    </table>
    ';

    $pdf->WriteHTML("

    $htmlTable

    <br /><br /><P style=\"font-size:10px; color:#ff0000; text-align:center; margin-bottom:4px;\">* Prices below are only an estimated price and is in no way an official cost from Vanguard Appraisals, Inc.</p><br />".$txt."<br /><center><p style=\"font-family: 'Century Gothic',CenturyGothic,AppleGothic,sans-serif; font-size:18px; width:90%; text-align:left;\">For an official price quote, or to get a quote on hardware items, please contact Vanguard Appraisals home office at (319)365-8625 or by e-mail at <a href=\"mailto:info@camavision.com\">info@camavision.com</a>.</p>");

    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',6);
    $pdf->Output();

    ?>


                            <div class="entry-content">
                            <?php

                                if(isset($_POST['send'])) {
                                    $to = "email@someemail.com"; 
                                    $txt = $_POST['data'];


                                    $filename = "Price_Estimate.pdf";
                                    $pdf->Output('Price_Estimate.pdf','D');
                                    $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($fileatt));
                                    $eol = PHP_EOL;
                                    $boundary = md5(time());

                                    function died($error) { 
                                        // your error code can go here   
                                        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";   
                                        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";   
                                        echo $error."<br /><br />";  
                                        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";     
                                        die();   
                                    }
                                    // validation expected data exists 
                                    if(!isset($_POST['Company']) ||  
                                        !isset($_POST['state']) ||   
                                        !isset($_POST['sales_rep']) ||
                                        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
                                        !isset($_POST['client']) ||
                                        !isset($_POST['client_email']) ||
                                        !isset($_POST['client_phone'])) {    
                                        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');    

                                    }
                                    $Company = $_POST['Company']; // required 
                                    $state = $_POST['state']; // required 
                                    $Sales = $_POST['sales_rep']; // required
                                    $from = $_POST['email']; // required
                                    $client = $_POST['client']; // required     
                                    $client_email = $_POST['client_email']; // not required 
                                    $client_phone = $_POST['client_phone']; // not required
                                    $date = date("F j, Y"); 



                                    $error_message = ""; 
                                    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';                                  
                                    if(!preg_match($email_exp,$from)) { 
                                        $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';        
                                    }
                                        $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
                                    if(!preg_match($string_exp,$Company)) { 
                                        $error_message .= 'The Company you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';      
                                    }
                                    if(!preg_match($string_exp,$Sales)) { 
                                        $error_message .= 'The Company you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';      
                                    }
                                    if(!preg_match($string_exp,$client)) { 
                                        $error_message .= 'The Company you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';      
                                    }   

                                    if(strlen($error_message) > 0) { 
                                        died($error_message); 
                                    }
                                        $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";
                                    function clean_string($string) { 
                                      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");    
                                      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);   
                                    }    
                                    $subject = "Price Quote Submission";;
                                    $subject2 = "Sales Copy of Price Quote Submission";


                                    //Web Copy                              
                                    $web_message .=  "<center><table align=\"center\"  style=\"width:85%; ;\"><tr> ";   
                                            $web_message .= "<td colspan=\"4\" align=\"center\" style=\"text-align:center;\" ><span style=\"text-transform:uppercase; font-weight:bold; font-size:20px; text-align:center;\">Contact Information</span></td>";
                                        $web_message .= "</tr><tr>";        
                                                $web_message .= "<td align=\"left\" style=\"background-color:#eee; padding-left:10px; width:20%; \"><b>Representative:</b></td>";
                                                $web_message .= "<td align=\"left\" style=\"padding-left:10px; background-color:#ffffff; width:30%;\">".clean_string($representative)."</td>";
                                                $web_message .= "<td align=\"left\" style=\"background-color:#eee; padding-left:10px; width:20%; \"><b>Rep's E-Mail:</b></td>";
                                                $web_message .= "<td align=\"left\" style=\"padding-left:10px; background-color:#ffffff; width:30%;\">".clean_string($from)."</td>";
                                            $web_message .= "</tr><tr>";
                                                $web_message .= "<td align=\"left\" style=\"background-color:#eee; padding-left:10px; width:20%; \"><b>client's Name:</b></td>";
                                                $web_message .= "<td align=\"left\" style=\"padding-left:10px; background-color:#ffffff; width:30%;\">".clean_string($client)."</td>";
                                                $web_message .= "<td align=\"left\" style=\"background-color:#eee; padding-left:10px; width:20%; \"><b>company, State:</b></td>";
                                                $web_message .= "<td align=\"left\" style=\"padding-left:10px; background-color:#ffffff; width:30%;\">".clean_string($company).", ".clean_string($state)."</td>";
                                            $web_message .= "</tr><tr>";
                                                $web_message .= "<td align=\"left\" style=\"background-color:#eee; padding-left:10px; width:20%; \"><b>Assessor's Phone:</b></td>";
                                                $web_message .= "<td align=\"left\" style=\"padding-left:10px; background-color:#ffffff; width:30%;\">".clean_string($client_phone)."</td>";
                                                $web_message .= "<td align=\"left\" style=\"background-color:#eee; padding-left:10px; width:20%; \"><b>client's E-mail:</b></td>";
                                                $web_message .= "<td align=\"left\" style=\"padding-left:10px; background-color:#ffffff; width:30%;\">".clean_string($email_from)."</td>";          
                                            $web_message .= "</tr>";
                                    $web_message .= "</tr></table></center><br /><br />";
                                    $web_message .= "<P style=\"font-size:10px; color:#ff0000; text-align:center; margin-bottom:4px;\">* Prices below are only an estimated price and is in no way an official cost .</p><br />".$txt."<br />";

                                        $web_message .= "<center><p style=\"font-family: 'Century Gothic',CenturyGothic,AppleGothic,sans-serif; font-size:18px; width:90%; text-align:left;\">For an official price quote, or to get a quote on hardware items, please contact home office.</p></center>";



                                    //Office Copy                               
                                    $message .= "<style> 
                                                table { width:700px; }
                                                table th { padding: 4px 10px; background-color: #396ba5; color:#ffffff; }
                                                table td {padding-bottom:0px; padding-top:0px; }
                                                td {padding-left:15px;}

                                                </style>";
                                    $message .= "<p style=\"text-align:center; font-size:10px;\">Some Company</p>";         
                                    $message .=  "<table align=\"center\" border=\"2\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"700\" style=\"border-collapse: collapse;\"><tr> ";
                                        $message .= "<td>";
                                            $message .= "<table align=\"center\" border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"700\"><tr>";
                                                $message .= "<td align=\"left\" style=\"padding:10px;\"><img src=\"" width=\"250\" height=\"56\" /></td>";
                                                $message .= "<td align=\"right\" style=\"padding:10px;\">Address<br />City, State, Zip Code<br />Telephone | Fax </td>";
                                            $message .= "</tr></table>";
                                        $message .= "</td>";
                                    $message .= "</tr><tr>";
                                        $message .= "<td align=\"center\" ><h2 style=\"text-transform:uppercase;\">Price Estimate</h2></td>";
                                    $message .= "</tr><tr>";
                                        $message .= "<td align=\"left\" style=\"padding:10px;\" >The following price quote was submitted on <b>".$date."</b> from ".clean_string($sales).".</td>";
                                    $message .= "</tr><tr>";
                                        $message .= "<td><br/>";
                                            $message .= "<table align=\"center\" border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"700\" ><tr>";
                                                $message .= "<td align=\"left\" style=\"background-color:#eee; padding-left:10px; \"><b>sales:</b></td>";
                                                $message .= "<td align=\"left\" style=\"padding-left:10px;\">".clean_string($sales)."</td>";
                                                $message .= "<td align=\"left\" style=\"background-color:#eee; padding-left:10px;\"><b>Rep's E-Mail:</b></td>";
                                                $message .= "<td align=\"left\" style=\"padding-left:10px;\">".clean_string($from)."</td>";
                                            $message .= "</tr><tr>";
                                                $message .= "<td align=\"left\" style=\"background-color:#eee; padding-left:10px;\"><b>client's Name:</b></td>";
                                                $message .= "<td align=\"left\" style=\" padding-left:10px;\">".clean_string($client)."</td>";
                                                $message .= "<td align=\"left\" style=\"background-color:#eee; padding-left:10px;\"><b>company, State:</b></td>";
                                                $message .= "<td align=\"left\" style=\"padding-left:10px;\">".clean_string($company).", ".clean_string($state)."</td>";
                                            $message .= "</tr><tr>";
                                                $message .= "<td align=\"left\" style=\"background-color:#eee; padding-left:10px;\"><b>client's Phone:</b></td>";
                                                $message .= "<td align=\"left\" style=\" padding-left:10px;\">".clean_string($client_phone)."</td>";
                                                $message .= "<td align=\"left\" style=\"background-color:#eee; padding-left:10px;\"><b>client's E-mail:</b></td>";
                                                $message .= "<td align=\"left\" style=\"padding-left:10px;\">".clean_string($email_from)."</td>";

                                            $message .= "</tr></table><br/><br/><br />";
                                        $message .= "</td>";

                                    $message .= "</tr><tr  >";
                                        $message .= "<td  style=\"padding:10px; text-align:center; border-bottom: 0px solid #ffffff;\"><span style=\"font-size:10px; color:#ff0000; text-align:center;\">* Prices below are only an estimated price and is in no way an official cost from Vanguard Appraisals, Inc.</span><br />".$txt."</td>";
                                    $message .= "</tr><tr>";
                                        $message .= "<td style=\"padding:10px; height:25px; border-top:0px solid #ffffff; border-bottom:0px solid #ffffff;\">&nbsp;</td>";
                                    $message .= "</tr><tr>";
                                        $message .= "<td align=\"center\" style=\"padding:10px;\" ><span style=\"font-size:10px; color:#ff0000; text-align:center;\">* Please do not reply back to this E-Mail</span></td> ";
                                    $message .= "</tr></table>";


                                    //sales Copy     
                                    $message2 .= "<style> 
                                                table { width:700px; }
                                                table th { padding: 4px 10px; background-color: #396ba5; color:#ffffff; }
                                                table td {padding-bottom:0px; padding-top:0px; }
                                                td {padding-left:15px;}
                                                </style>";
                                    $message2 .= "<p style=\"text-align:center; font-size:10px;\">Price Estimat</p>";           
                                    $message2 .=  "<table align=\"center\" border=\"2\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"700\" style=\"border-collapse: collapse;\"><tr> ";
                                        $message2 .= "<td>";
                                            $message2 .= "<table align=\"center\" border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"700\"><tr>";
                                                $message2 .= "<td align=\"left\" style=\"padding:10px;\"><img src=\"http://demo.camavision.com/VCSWeb/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/BLUE-Vanguard-horizontal_250x56.jpg\" width=\"250\" height=\"56\" /></td>";
                                                $message2 .= "<td align=\"right\" style=\"padding:10px;\">Address<br />City, State Zip<br />Telephone | Fax</td>";
                                            $message2 .= "</tr></table>";
                                        $message2 .= "</td>";
                                    $message2 .= "</tr><tr>";
                                        $message2 .= "<td align=\"center\" ><h2 style=\"text-transform:uppercase;\">Price Estimate</h2></td>";
                                    $message2 .= "</tr><tr>";
                                        $message2 .= "<td align=\"left\" style=\"padding:10px;\" ><h3 align=\"center\" style=\"text-align:center;\">".$date."</h3>Thank you for submitting the following price quote on ".$date.". It has been successfully submited to the home office. You can see the items selected and an estimated cost below. Please remember that this is just an estimated cost and it is in no way an official cost . Please contact the home office .<br/><br/></td>";
                                    $message2 .= "</tr><tr>";
                                        $message2 .= "<td><br/>";
                                            $message2 .= "<table align=\"center\" border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"700\" ><tr>";
                                                $message2 .= "<td align=\"left\" style=\"background-color:#eee; padding-left:10px;\"><b>client's Name:</b></td>";
                                                $message2 .= "<td align=\"left\" style=\" padding-left:10px;\">".clean_string($client)."</td>";
                                                $message2 .= "<td align=\"left\" style=\"background-color:#eee; padding-left:10px;\"><b>company, State:</b></td>";
                                                $message2 .= "<td align=\"left\" style=\"padding-left:10px;\">".clean_string($company).", ".clean_string($state)."</td>";
                                            $message2 .= "</tr><tr>";
                                                $message2 .= "<td align=\"left\" style=\"background-color:#eee; padding-left:10px;\"><b>client's Phone:</b></td>";
                                                $message2 .= "<td align=\"left\" style=\" padding-left:10px;\">".clean_string($client_phone)."</td>";
                                                $message2 .= "<td align=\"left\" style=\"background-color:#eee; padding-left:10px;\"><b>client's E-mail:</b></td>";
                                                $message2 .= "<td align=\"left\" style=\"padding-left:10px;\">".clean_string($email_from)."</td>";

                                            $message2 .= "</tr></table><br/><br/><br />";
                                        $message2 .= "</td>";                                   
                                    $message2 .= "</tr><tr  >";
                                        $message2 .= "<td  style=\"padding:10px; text-align:center;\"><span style=\"font-size:10px; color:#ff0000; text-align:center;\">* Prices below are only an estimated price and is in no way an official cost.</span><br />".$txt."</td>";
                                    $message2 .= "</tr><tr>";
                                        $message2 .= "<td style=\"padding:10px; border-bottom:0px solid #ffffff;\">For an official price quote, or to receive a quote on hardware items, please contact home office .</td>";
                                    $message2 .= "</tr><tr>";
                                        $message2 .= "<td style=\"padding:10px; height:25px; border-top:0px solid #ffffff; border-bottom:0px solid #ffffff;\">&nbsp;</td>";
                                    $message2 .= "</tr><tr>";
                                        $message2 .= "<td align=\"center\" style=\"padding:10px;\" ><span style=\"font-size:10px; color:#ff0000; text-align:center;\">* Please do not reply back to this E-Mail</span></td> ";
                                    $message2 .= "</tr></table>";


                                    // main header (multipart mandatory)
                                    $headers  = "From: ".clean_string($from);
                                    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0"; 
                                    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;boundary=\"" . $boundary . "\"\r\n"; 


                                    // attachment
                                    $output = "--".$boundary."\r\n";
                                    $output .= "Content-Type: text/pdf; name=\"Price_Estimate.pdf\";\r\n";
                                    $output .= "Content-Disposition: attachment;\r\n\r\n";                              
                                    $output .= $attachment."\r\n\r\n";
                                    $output .= "--".$boundary."\r\n";
                                     $output .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n";
                                    $output .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n\r\n";
                                    $output .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
                                    $output .= "--".$boundary."--\r\n\r\n";



                                    // create sales email headers
                                    $headers2 = "From: ".$to. "\r\n";
                                    $headers2 .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
                                    $headers2 .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
                                    $headers2 .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit";
                                    $headers2 .= $message.$eol.$eol;



                                    mail($to,$subject,$output,$headers);
                                    mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); 

                                    if(mail($to,$subject,$output,$headers))
                                       {
                                         echo "<p style=\"font-family: 'Century Gothic',CenturyGothic,AppleGothic,sans-serif; font-size:18px; margin-top:-50px;\" >Thank you for submitting the following price quote on ".$date.". It has been successfully submited to the home office. You can see the items selected and an estimated cost below. Please remember that this is just an estimated cost and it is in no way an official cost from Vanguard Appraisals, Inc. Please contact the home office .</p>";
                                       }
                                       else
                                       {
                                         echo "<p style=\"font-family: 'Century Gothic',CenturyGothic,AppleGothic,sans-serif; font-size:18px; margin-top:-50px;\" >We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the price quote you submitted. Please return back to the price quote page and try re-submitting the form again.  Any questions or to receive an official estimate by phone, please contact the home office.  Thank you.</p>";
                                       }
                            ?>



                            <!-- include your own success html here -->


                            <div style="width:100%;"> 

                            <?php echo $web_message ?>
                            </div> 

                            <?php

                            }

                            ?>

                        </div>

                        </article>
                    </div><!-- #main -->
```

Comment: Please remove any code that is not relevant to the core of your question. No one is going to read and analyze all of that.

Comment: you'd have to do somethignl ike `ob_start(); $pdf->Output(); $pdf = ob_get_clean()`, then use something like PHPmailer's "attach from string" to attach that $pdf var to the email. what you're doing is dumping out the raw PDF bytes, followed by the rest of your html page, which technically corrupts the pdf. it's not a pdf anymore. it's a pdf followed by html.

Comment: So how would I seperate the pdf from the HTML email element and then send the PDF as an attachment?

Comment: Using ob_start() and the $pdf= ob_get_clean(), how will I send the two seperate emails as html.  does it work the same.  where would I plug this in?

Comment: Can Anyone give me examples, or where to start or how to fix!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this .. it opens a new window which contains your html data and pdf printing option.

```
var content = "<div>html content</div";
win = window.open();
self.focus();
win.document.open();
win.document.write(content);
win.document.close();
win.focus();
win.print();
```

Comment: its close but still need to send the data as an attachment (perferably pdf).